# React Native: Autocomplete text input with tags

Tags: autocomplete, react-native, tags

Is there any library that provides autocomplete text input with a functionality of adding/removing tags like [this lib for React](http://reactscript.com/react-token-autocomplete-component/). I want to add tag when dropdown with suggestions is shown in autocomplete and remove tags clicking on them.

Comment: the closest example i've seen is [react-native-tag-input](https://github.com/jwohlfert23/react-native-tag-input)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, maybe too much of  a necro.  Good luck!

https://github.com/JoeRoddy/react-native-tag-autocomplete